# Website monitoring with zabbix

Tags: zabbix

We have multiple webservers serving multiple websites.

In Zabbix I have configured the following:-

- Web scenario template
- Individual hosts for each website

This works...but...

What I would like to do associate the websites with the host where they are hosted, rather than having the sites as individual host records, and using the web scenario template i've created, rather than creating multiple ones.

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

No. If [LLD supported web scenarios](https://support.zabbix.com/browse/ZBXNEXT-2621), you could generate them that way, but that's not available yet.

Your best bet might be grouping website hosts in host groups per server.